# How to line break when I foreach a php array?

Tags: php

I have an array with a reference, a price and a quantity in an array. I have a `foreach` set in a html table, and I would like a line break after each quantity but I can't make it work.

```
 if (isset($_SESSION["buy"])) :
        $cart = $_SESSION["buy"];
    endif;

 if (!empty($_POST["quantity"])) :
     array_push($cart, $_POST['ref']);
     array_push($cart, $_POST['price']);
     array_push($cart, $_POST["quantity"]);
     $_SESSION["buy"] = $cart;
 endif;




<table>
    <thead>Your order</thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Ref</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($cart as $row => $data) : ?>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $data; ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

Whatever I try, the result will only be a single column or row.
How can I force it to line break after each `$data(quantity)`

Comment: let me see the result of  <?php echo $data; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it would help that when you store the details, you store them together - at the moment you are mixing all the details in the same array...

```
 if (!empty($_POST["quantity"])) :
     array_push($cart, $_POST['ref']);
     array_push($cart, $_POST['price']);
     array_push($cart, $_POST["quantity"]);
     $_SESSION["buy"] = $cart;
 endif;
```

I would suggest an associative array with the details of each item in the same element of `$cart`...

```
 if (!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
     array_push($cart,["ref" => $_POST['ref'], 
                "price" =>$_POST['price'] 
                "quantity" => $_POST["quantity"]);
     $_SESSION["buy"] = $cart;
 }
```

Then to display the results, echo each line in it's own `<tr>` tags with each item in a `<td>` , you could also apply formatting to each item according to what you need...

```
foreach ( $cart as $item ) {
     echo "<tr><td>{$item[ref]}</td><td>{$item[price]}</td><td>{$item[quantity])</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added some " " there and there to make it work. I only started php this week and I was not able to do it on my own. Thank you for your code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This code, maybe this code will be help you :

```
<table>
                    <thead>Your order</thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ref</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>Quantity</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($cart as $row) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $row['ref']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $row['price']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $row['quantity']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>
```